# Can't match string using regular expression with "?"

Tags: c#, regex

I need to build regular expression to match following strings:

1. CCN
2. CreditCardNum
3. CreditCardNUmber
4. CCNumber

etc.

I built it as follows : `C(redit)?C(ard)?N(um|umber)?`
It doesn't match "*CreditCardNumber*" string.
I also tried : `C(redit)?C(ard)?N(:?um|umber)` without success

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your pattern is good, all you need to add is: `(?i)` at the begining

or IgnoreCase in the regex options. `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`

Note: since you don't need to capture "redit" or "ard", non capturing groups `(?:...)` are better:

```
(?i)C(?:redit)?C(?:ard)?N(?:um(?:ber)?)?
```

If you want to have more control with the case:

```
C(?i:redit)?C(?i:ard)?N(?i:um(?:ber)?)?
```

For more security you can add word boundaries at the begining and at the end of the pattern `\b`

Comment: Instead of making regex a mess with `(?:)`, you can use `RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture`/`(?n)`. `(?in)C(redit)?C(ard)?N(um(ber)?)?`

Comment: @Athari: indeed, but you loose the flexibility to use inline modifiers at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
(?i)C(?:redit)?C(?:ard)?N(?:um(?:ber)?)?
```

`(?i)` is to make your regex case insensitive.